# How to combine both vertical and horizontal layout of clusters and nodes using graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

I am experimenting with graphviz to visualize the requirements traceability documentation.

This is what I would like to achieve:

- One document to the left side, another to the right side.
- Within each document, the chapters are laid out vertically.
- Within each chapter, the nodes are laid out vertically.

I tried to replace LR with TB and experimented with `rankdir=same` and assigning `rank` to the nodes, but could not get it to work.

My goals:

- Achieve the desired layout.
- Make sure that the nodes within the clusters are also sorted correctly. I figured out that for these nodes, I can fix the order using invisible links, but maybe there is a better approach.
- Eventually, I am going to generate this code automatically for rather large documents, so no preference to the hard-coded solutions.

This is my code.

```
digraph {
  rankdir=LR;
  subgraph cluster_document_1 {
    subgraph cluster_document_1_chapter_1 {
      {
        D1_C1_E1[label="Chapter 1.1"]
        D1_C1_E2[label="Chapter 1.2"]
      }
    }
    subgraph cluster_document_1_chapter_2 {
      {
        D1_C2_E1[label="Chapter 2.1"];
        D1_C2_E2[label="Chapter 2.2"];
      }
    }
  }
  subgraph cluster_document_2 {
    subgraph cluster_document_2_chapter_1 {
      {
        D2_C1_E1[label="Chapter 1.1"];
        D2_C1_E2[label="Chapter 1.2"];
      }
    }
    subgraph cluster_document_2_chapter_2 {
      {
        D2_C2_E1[label="Chapter 2.1"];
        D2_C2_E2[label="Chapter 2.2"];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**This is what I DON'T want:**

[image]

[image]

**This is how I want it to look like:**

[image]

Comment: How do you want left-right alignment to work if document A, chapter 2 has more subchapters than document B, chapter 2?  Do you want to re-align at Chapter 3 or keep unaligned?

Comment: Definitely unaligned because my documents can be of very arbitrary structure. The goal is to have both documents simply grow down with their contents. The next level challenge (outside this SO question) would be to establish horizontal relationships between the nodes (requirements) of both documents. If a document has fewer chapters, so be it, no specific alignment is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the question, I don't think there is a way around invisible edges for your use case.

Fortunately, it's quite easy to generate those edges automatically - simply create a chain of edges from the first to the last chapter.

Example:

```
digraph {
  edge[style=invis]
  subgraph cluster_document_1 {
    subgraph cluster_document_1_chapter_1 {
      {
        D1_C1_E1[label="Chapter 1.1"]
        D1_C1_E2[label="Chapter 1.2"]
      }
    }
    subgraph cluster_document_1_chapter_2 {
      {
        D1_C2_E1[label="Chapter 2.1"];
        D1_C2_E2[label="Chapter 2.2"];
      }
    }
    
    D1_C1_E1 -> D1_C1_E2 -> D1_C2_E1 -> D1_C2_E2
  }
  subgraph cluster_document_2 {
    subgraph cluster_document_2_chapter_1 {
      {
        D2_C1_E1[label="Chapter 1.1"];
        D2_C1_E2[label="Chapter 1.2"];
        D2_C1_E3[label="Chapter 1.3"];
      }
    }
    subgraph cluster_document_2_chapter_2 {
      {
        D2_C2_E1[label="Chapter 2.1"];
        D2_C2_E2[label="Chapter 2.2"];
      }
    }
    D2_C1_E1 -> D2_C1_E2 -> D2_C1_E3 -> D2_C2_E1 -> D2_C2_E2
  }
}
```

[image: graphviz output]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have managed to integrate your solution to my program that generates this graph automatically. One last question: the invisible edges still increase the distance between the nodes. Is there a way to reduce the distance between nodes? A specific example to make it clear: Chapter 2.1 and Chapter 2.2 should be closer to each other. Thank you.

Comment: Look at ranksep (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/ranksep/)

Answer (score 1):

[I wonder if your example is too simplified.
I added a bit of complexity (more sections in one document), but at some point you might consider removing all the clusters and just go with one or two html-like nodes. (https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#recreating-the-record-example)
]

- changed **rankdir**
- added **newrank** (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/newrank/), to allow ranking across clusters
- invisible edges to rank the chapters and sections (sub-chapters)

```
digraph {
  // rankdir=LR;
  newrank=true  // allow rank= across clusters

  edge[style=invis]  // invis edges to rank nodes horizontally

  subgraph cluster_document_1 {
    subgraph cluster_document_1_chapter_1 {
      {
        D1_C1_E1[label="Chapter 1.1"]
        D1_C1_E2[label="Chapter 1.2"]
        D1_C1_E3[label="Chapter 1.3"]
        D1_C1_E4[label="Chapter 1.4"]

    D1_C1_E1-> D1_C1_E2-> D1_C1_E3-> D1_C1_E4
      }
    }
    subgraph cluster_document_1_chapter_2 {
      {
        D1_C2_E1[label="Chapter 2.1"];
        D1_C2_E2[label="Chapter 2.2"];

    D1_C2_E1-> D1_C2_E2
      }
    }
    // now align chapter after chapter

    D1_C1_E4-> D1_C2_E1  // last in chapter to first in next chapter
  }
  subgraph cluster_document_2 {
    subgraph cluster_document_2_chapter_1 {
      {
        D2_C1_E1[label="Chapter 1.1"];
        D2_C1_E2[label="Chapter 1.2"];

    D2_C1_E1-> D2_C1_E2
      }
    }
    subgraph cluster_document_2_chapter_2 {
      {
        D2_C2_E1[label="Chapter 2.1"];
        D2_C2_E2[label="Chapter 2.2"];

    D2_C2_E1-> D2_C2_E2
      }
    }
      // now align chapter after chapter
    D2_C1_E2-> D2_C2_E1  // last in chapter to first in next chapter 
  }
  // now align the subchapters, side-by-side
  // or don't, if unwanted
  {rank=same D1_C1_E1 D2_C1_E1 }
  {rank=same D1_C1_E2 D2_C1_E2 }
  
  {rank=same D1_C2_E1 D2_C2_E1 }  
  {rank=same D1_C2_E2 D2_C2_E2 }  
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried both your and @marapet's answers and they both have worked. I ended up using the other answer as something that is easier to generate with my program. I have a follow-up question that applies to both answers, please see it in my other comment to the other answer (reduce the length of invisible edges).